# HTML - Open local PDF in a new window using a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to open a pdf file using a button in my project.

Given this code:

```
 <button type=submit class="btn btn-danger" onclick=" window.open('file:////C:\Users\data'); return true;"> PDF </button>
```

It just opens a about:blank page. What seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be linking to a local file on your own pc. You need to upload the file to your server, like you would do with images, and then link to the path that you place it in.

You should also be able to use `target="_blank"` for this rather than onclick.
Here is an example set up for the html:

```
<a href="/books/a-great-book.pdf" target="_blank">
```