# How do I assign a href to a button that when you click it opens a pdf

Tags: html

this is the hierarchy where the file is.

[image]

```html
<td>
     <a  class="btn btn-info" href="/Files/MeetingMin/MM-09_20_2020.pdf">
       09/20/2020
     </a>
</td>
```

Comment: look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434853/html-open-local-pdf-in-a-new-window-using-a-button

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I already did that and it did not work

Comment: In which directory is this html file? Because it looks like it is in the Files directory. Do this if it is: `<a  class="btn btn-info" href="MeetingMin/MM-09_20_2020.pdf">`

Comment: @SoWhatNow2022, what exactly didn't work? And how do you want to display pdf?

Comment: @virejdasani  I kept thinking I was in the mail directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just remove `/Files/` - your HTML is one higher than the folder with the pdf files - add target="_blank" to open in a new tab
2. Style the link as a button https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357227/295783

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4E9CAF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-info" href="MeetingMin/MM-09_20_2020.pdf" target="_blank">09/20/2020</a>
```